# I'm assuming my laptop is hacked by police?

Tags: windows, firefox

I'd like some quick tips to find out about my privacy being invaded. I've tried task manager and msconfig.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It would also be inappropriate on Super User as written, because there isn't nearly enough detail.  For example, you need to explain what makes you think your laptop is being "hacked by police".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use PeerBlock, it's a really good firewall and gives you a Log (once it said that some prince was trying to enter my pc, wtf?!) http://peerblock.com/

Comment: A peer of the realm, presumably. :-)